# How to Send All SQLite Data to online Server

Tags: android, sqlite

I am ***storing data into SQLiteDatabase*** which is stored into SD Card, now i **have to send all SQLite data to server**.
Note: I have **created same fields to server database** as well (**simillar** to SQLite DB) for an eg: **PersonName**

Below code i used to check, am i able **to store data to server** (for testing purpose - i **accepted data by user into edittext**) and then ***sent to server***, and i **was successful** in that.

```
String url = "http://localhost/ChurchData.php";                                         
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sPersonName", editPersonName.getText().toString()));
String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
Log.d("Entire string::", " " + resultServer);

/*** Default Value ***/
strStatusID = "0";
strError = "";

JSONObject c;
try {
c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
strError = c.getString("Message");
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
 }
 // prepare save data
 if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
 {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Exist !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else
 {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                          
 }
 return true;
}

private String getHttpPost(String url,
 List<NameValuePair> params) {
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
 try {
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
str.append(line);
}
} else {
Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
}
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
 return str.toString();
}
```

So may i know, ***How can i send SQLite database records to server*** ? My **database class** looks like this:

```
public class myDBClasss extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ChurchDB";
    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "DataTable";

    public myDBClasss(Context context) {
        // to store data into SD Card   
       super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "ChurchData"
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create Table Name
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
                  "(PersonName VARCHAR(100)," +
                  " PersonEmail VARCHAR(100)," +
                  " PersonTelephone VARCHAR(100)," +
                  " Newsletter VARCHAR(100));");       // checkbox

        Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully - classs");
    }

    // Insert Data
    public long insertData(String strPersonName, String strPersonEmail, String strPersonTelephone, String strNewsletter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues(); 
            Val.put("PersonName", strPersonName);
            Val.put("PersonEmail", strPersonEmail);
            Val.put("PersonTelephone", strPersonTelephone);
            Val.put("Newsletter", strNewsletter);       // checkbox

            long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows inserted.

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
         }
    }

    // Update Data
    public long updateData(String strPersonName, String strPersonEmail, String strPersonTelephone, String strNewsletter){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("PersonName", strPersonName);
            Val.put("PersonEmail", strPersonEmail);
                    Val.put("PersonTelephone", strPersonTelephone);
            Val.put("Newsletter", strNewsletter);       // checkbox

            long rows = db.update(TABLE_MEMBER, Val, "PersonName=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(strPersonName) });

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows updated.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }   
    }

    // Fetch data
    public String[] selectData(String strPersonName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            String arrData[] = null;    

             SQLiteDatabase db;
             db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

             Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBER, new String[] { "*" }, 
                        "PersonName=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(strPersonName) }, null, null, null, null);

                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];

                        arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0);
                        arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                        arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2);
                        arrData[3] = cursor.getString(3);       // checkbox
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                return arrData;

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
         }
    }

    // Check for data(s) using PersonName field
    public boolean exists(String strImageName) {
           SQLiteDatabase db;
           db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select 1 from DataTable where PersonName= ?", 
                new String[] { strImageName });
           boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
           cursor.close();
           return exists;
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
        // Re Create on method  onCreate
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think easy way is that you convert all your sqlite data into xml or json and then only one http request is required to send all your data to online server. At online server you can easily parse your data as you already know the structure of your xml or json whatever you used.

let say you have 2 fields in your database. ID , Name. you have 10 records. you convert all your records into json .

let say you query your database for all records and now `cursor` object will hold all your sqlite data.

add `getAllData()` method to retrieve all your database data.

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
     String selectQuery = "Select * from "+TABLE_MEMBER; 
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
     return cursor;
}
```

now do,

```
Cursor cursor = getAllData();  //cursor hold all your data
JSONObject jobj ;
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
cursor.moveToFIrst();
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
   jobj = new JSONObject();
   jboj.put("Id", cursor.getInt("Id"));
   jboj.put("Name", cursor.getString("Name"));
   arr.put(jobj);
}

jobj = new JSONObject();
jobj.put("data", arr);

String st = jboj.toString();
```

now simply make an http call with string parameter and send to server.and parse at server by converting this string into jsonobject.

now according to your code, do

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("allData", st));
String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
```

Comment: thanks, please check code i posted above and let me know where i have to make change !

Comment: replace your http request coe with the one that i added.

Comment: will you clear in your code where you are converting my Database records to JSON (because i guess you have not used my database name anywhere in your code)

Comment: i have used cursor object. cursor object will hold all your data.

Comment: yes i saw you used Cursor but again friend, you have not used my database name anywhere in your code

Comment: sophie, let say you have a method in your database helper class . i called that method and it returned a cursor object with all your data. thats what i assumed.

Comment: waqar for your support and guidance i accepted your answer, but still facing issue, but if i will need your help then will ping you sure and whenever i will complete will let you know the final solution! OK

Comment: The json file sent to the server as what type of file? Also how can I read it back into the Android application? Thank you. Let me know if you would like me to open a new Q.

Comment: How can I implememnt this answer using Volley? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have some snippet of code just for your idea.If it help you it my pleasure.

```
           protected void startSync(Context aContext) {
    try {
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
        Account[] ac = am.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        if (ac.length > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(SuperHomeActivity.this,
                    "Synchronization Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            List<PeriodicSync> aList = ContentResolver.getPeriodicSyncs(
                    ac[0], Constants.AUTHORITY);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, false);
            if (aList != null && aList.size() > 0) {
                while (aList != null && !aList.isEmpty()) {
                    ContentResolver.removePeriodicSync(ac[0],
                            Constants.AUTHORITY, aList.get(0).extras);
                    aList.remove(0);
                }
            }
            // mention only in seconds -> 120 minutes 60 seconds
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(ac[0], Constants.AUTHORITY,
                    bundle, 5 * 60); //15
            ContentResolver.requestSync(ac[0], Constants.AUTHORITY, bundle);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("SyncAccountTriggerError", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And you can call it by

```
                startSync(getApplicationContext());
```

For any more clarification you can ping me.

Comment: But in my case, data stored to SQLite database which is created in SD Card, so how can i fetch and send all records to server from SQLite

Comment: And another thing is that you send whole db or content of db?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Http Post method or Get method or if you directly wants to update your server DB then use Put method. You can send data by http request with NameValue pair and just get that data from server and update your DB. That's it.

Comment: i suggest you to read my question once again, i already mentioned data already stored to sqlite and now need to send all sqlite data to server and if you will see my code which i posted above i am also using NameValue pair using post method to send data to server

Comment: ya then why do you have asked this question? if all thing is working properly dear?

Comment: Your database created in SD card or you export there?

Comment: @pratik like i wrote you should read my question first before answering or commenting !